# any(Class.class) equivalent in kotlin mockito

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

In java we would do the following:

```
verify(myTestObject).execute(any(Callback.class))
```

In kotlin if I use `any(Callback::class)` I get "too many arguments for public fun  any(): T defined in com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to specify the class as generic type argument:

```
verify(myTestObject).execute(any<Callback>())
```

Or, due to type inference, you can leave it out:

```
verify(myTestObject).execute(any())
```